# Compute the following integral by using cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the value of the integral of $g(z)$ around the circle $|z-i|=2$ in the positive sense when

(a) $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+4}$ answer a)$\pi/2$

Hint: Use Cauchy's integral formula

Approach: $$\frac{1}{z^2+4}=\frac{\frac{1}{4i}}{z-2i}+\frac{\frac{-1}{4i}}{z+2i}$$

Applying cauchy's formula, the integral would be $2\pi i*\frac{1}{4i}-2\pi i(\frac{1}{4i})=0$

but that's not the right answer and based on my derivation $-2i$ is not defined on the contour because the countour is a circle of radius 1 centered around i, so it doesn't touch $-2i$

Comment: Where did you get the zero from? The contour of integration is important.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\dfrac{1}{z+2i}$ is holomorphic within the contour, which wraps around $2i$, not around $-2i$. Only the term containing $\dfrac{1}{z-2i}$ will yield an integral that does not vanish; that is to say, the other term does not contribute to the value of the integral.